# go un/marshal struct as json

Tags: go, marshalling

I need to wrap json rpc messages in a go struct
This was my first idea and it's working for outgoing messages like this

```
// Message wrapper
type Message struct {
    ID      *string      `json:"id,omitempty"`
    JSONRPC string       `json:"jsonrpc"`
    Method  *string      `json:"method,omitempty"`
    Params  *interface{} `json:"params,omitempty"`
    Result  *interface{} `json:"result,omitempty"`
}

// NewNotification creates a RPC Notification
func NewNotification(method string, params interface{}) Message {

    m := Message{}
    m.JSONRPC = "2.0"
    m.Method = &method
    m.Params = &params

    return m

}

type Test struct {
        A string `json:"a"`
        B string `json:"b"`
}

t := Test{"abc", "def"}

m := NewNotification("testMethod", t)

socket.WriteJSON(m)
```

But now for the receiving direction I have a problem with the 
`Params *interface{}` declaration.

I identify the `Params` payload type via the `Method` field and want to 
unmarshal the `Params` to that struct ... but therefore I need the type 
`json.RawMessage` for `Params` to get this working.

I do not want to define a `MessageIn` and `MessageOut` struct!

```
m := Message{}
socket.ReadJSON(m)

t := Test{}

json.Unmarshal(m.Params, &t)
```

Comment: Try pre-declaring an instance of the destination type: `var mesg json.RawMessage; var params interface{} = &mesg; Test{Params: &params}`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `json.RawMessage` as the type for your Params and Result Fields. This will delay the decoding of the these fields until you know what is the Method, on the receiving end. Check out the documentation and the examples: it's the same use case: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage

Comment: yes that's ok but than I have to marshal the Params/Result in sending and receiving direction manually

Answer (score 0):

Ok this idea has a `MessageIn` and `MessageOut` struct but they share the common part from `Message`. This way it's possible to let WriteJson do the marshalling in sending direction. The receiving unmarshal must be done manually when the method and the supposed payload type is known.

```
// Message wrapper
type Message struct {
    ID      *string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    JSONRPC string  `json:"jsonrpc"`
    Method  *string `json:"method,omitempty"`
}

// MessageIn wrapper
type MessageIn struct {
    Message
    Params *json.RawMessage `json:"params,omitempty"`
    Result *json.RawMessage `json:"result,omitempty"`
}

// MessageOut wrapper
type MessageOut struct {
    Message
    Params *interface{} `json:"params,omitempty"`
    Result *interface{} `json:"result,omitempty"`
}

// NewNotification creates a RPC Notification
func NewNotification(method string, params interface{}) MessageOut {

    m := MessageOut{}
    m.JSONRPC = "2.0"
    m.Method = &method
    m.Params = &params

    return m

}

type Test struct {
        A string `json:"a"`
        B string `json:"b"`
}

# let WriteJSON do all marshalling 
t := Test{"abc", "def"}

m := NewNotification("testMethod", t)

socket.WriteJSON(m)

# unmarshal manually received message when method is known
m := Message{}
socket.ReadJSON(m)

t := Test{}

json.Unmarshal(m.Params, &t)
```